# Show that $(A*B*A^{-1})^2 = B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that $(A*B*A^{-1})^2 = B^2$

I tried:

$(A*B*A^{-1})*(A*B*A^{-1})$ $\hspace{5mm}$ (1)

$= A*B*A^{-1}*A*B*A{-1}$  $\hspace{5mm}$ (2)

$= A*B*B*A^{-1}$ $\hspace{5mm}$ (3)

$ = A*B^2*A^{-1}$ $\hspace{5mm}$ (4)

In step $(4)$ I do not know how to clear $B ^ 2$

Comment: Note that $(A B A^{-1})^n =A B^n A^{-1}$. Also, if $AB = BA$ then $A B^n A^{-1} = B^n$.

Comment: You are indeed right. Without further assumptions (4) is as far you can get

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for answering, I do not understand, why AB = BA?

Comment: @MathLover then we can only say that it is true in case AB = BA

Comment: @peterxd4 Yes, if $A$ and $B$ commute, i.e., $AB = BA$, then we can say $(A B A^{-1})^n = B^n$.

Comment: @MathLover I already understand it, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not hold in general.

Let $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\2&3\end{matrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)$. Then $$(ABA^{-1})^2=\left[\left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\2&3\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1\\-2&1\end{matrix}\right)\right]^2=\left(\begin{matrix}9&-3\\21&-6\end{matrix}\right)$$ whereas $$B^2=\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1\\1&2\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&-3\\3&3\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Therefore we can only affirm that it is true in case AB = BA

Comment: Yes. If $AB=BA$ then step $4$ becomes: $$AB^2A^{-1}=(AB)BA^{-1}=B(AB)A^{-1}=B^2AA^{-1}=B^2$$ as required.

Comment: or, say if $B^2$ is in the *centre*, i.e. $B^2=\lambda I$, then $AB^2A^{-1}=B^2$.